# How do I use ASM to edit java code in compile time (using Gradle)

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, java-bytecode-asm

What I need to know is how do I use ASM code to modify classes generated by the Gradle `build` task in **compile-time** (without using any agent, cause that would be *loadtime/runtime*), there's a bunch of ASM tutorials on the Internet, but none of them teach how do I use it to edit code generated by the `javac` in compile-time.

I have two reasons to do this: first, I want to learn more about the java bytecode, and second, I want to have this tool on my belt for when the time comes I'll be able to use it.

Please, teach me with a brief example how to do this, and where do I put my ASM files so I can use them through Gradle, I would also love links to any tutorial that you might know about using ASM at compile-time. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The ASM library is a tool to process byte arrays in a specific format, [the class file format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html). Whether you get the byte arrays directly from `javac` or read them from the hardrive or receive them from the Instrumentation API at runtime, is irrelevant. It doesn’t matter to the ASM library and the way you use it. Any tutorial will do.